# UIImageView does not fit my screen properly

Tags: swift, uiimageview, ios8, autolayout

I have a UIImageView that fills up the majority of my screen, with the exception of a navigationBar at the top. On my storyboard, I am using the formatting mode titled "compact width|regular height" that is supposed to work for all iPhones in portrait mode. When I attempt to run my app on an iPhone 5c, with iOS8, the imageView does not fill to fit the screen, and appears to "spill out" of the screen, based on the size and positioning of the image within the imageView. I do not have any auto-layout constraints on my imageView, because when I attempt to put them on they enlarge and distort the image even further. I have tried Scale to Fill, Aspect Fill, and Aspect Fit, and none of those work. I have also made sure that the clip to subviews selection button has been checked, so that the bounds are clipped. If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the auto-layout and use the autoresizing mask.
I used this on images and fixed the prob like yours that I had.